# Error when I try to source ~/.bashrc Ubuntu 18

Tags: bash, bashrc, source

while trying to update node js I think I somehow broke my bash configuration.

When I try to execute `source ~/.bashrc` I get the following:

[image: Command output]

I really hope you can help me.

Comment: Pasting command outputs as plain, code-formatted text is generally preferred over screenshots, if possible, as it is better accessible. Might it be that you are running a non-Bash shell? `shopt` and `complete` are Bash builtins. Check the output of `echo "$SHELL $0"`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're still looking for an answer, but the problem is that the shell you're using isn't bash (it's probably zsh, I had the same problem with it)

try writing `echo $0` to find out what shell you're using, and then use the appropriate file for source (for instance `source ~/.zshrc` if you're on zsh)

Answer (score 0):

Type `locate .bashrc` and you will see:

```
/etc/skel/.bashrc
/home/your_user_name/.bashrc~
```

First backup your corrupted file:

```
cp /home/your_user_name/.bashrc /home/your_user_name/.bashrc.bak
```

Then try your backup created by your editor:

```
cp /home/your_user_name/.bashrc~ /home/your_user_name/.bashrc
```

If that doesn't work use the skeleton version:

```
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc /home/your_user_name/.bashrc
```

Then copy in changes from your backup version just made up to the point of the node js changes that broke it.